# How to get HTTP request body size in Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, google-cloud-functions

I would like to retrieve the size of the request body to filter out the large HTTP post request.
So, How can I get the length of the request?

Comment: are you asking to get the limit request body size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per its documentation, Cloud Functions has a hard limit of `10 MB` for HTTP request and response payloads. For more detail, you can check [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas).
and also, you cannot extend the limit as well(I have not found yet).

Just to check the length of your request, you can use `req.get("content-length")`.